# Trying to make one user profile

Tags: php, visual-studio, laravel-6

Below is my logout form.

**app.blade.php**

```html
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" 
    method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
</form>
```

I have the login and registration forms but when I try to click logout I get the following error.

> Undefined variable: request

**api.php**

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'UserController@AuthRouteAPI');

return $request->user();
```

I have tried but I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: You shouldn't do logout login in the route file (api.php).
Use controller action instead (UserController@logout).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel built-in Auth system features - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#logging-out